# Android studio - creating transition/animation for an ImageView using Interpolator(s)

Tags: android, animation, button, transition

I was wondering if someone could help me with my code. Down bellow is the code
that I found on the internet, and adjust it a bit. So for a button is set a **onClickListener** method, that includes two methods, which are used when the button is pressed. So the code works, but not the way I imagined it to. When the button is pressed, it dissapears and flows in to the screen from the left with it's **AccelerateInterpolator.** What I would like it to do and for other buttons that are in my application is that. when the button is pressed it would go from **it's current location** (let's say -center of the screen) and it would flow out of the screen and then **coming back to it's location**.

I don't know how to set the parameters right or to change the methods.
thanks for the help

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {


            findViewById(R.id.button1);

            TranslateAnimation translation;
            translation = new TranslateAnimation(getDisplayHeight(), 0f, 0f, 0f);
            translation.setStartOffset(500);
            translation.setDuration(2000);
            translation.setFillAfter(true);
            translation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            findViewById(R.id.button1).startAnimation(translation);

            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

        private int getDisplayHeight() {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            return metrics.widthPixels;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So 1st you aren't using translateanimation properly.

```
TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

So to move from its current location to a new location would be:

```
TranslateAnimation(0, 'change in X value you want', 0, 'change in Y value you want')
```

2nd to make it come back you could set the repeat count to 1 and the mode to reverse, (another way to do it would be create another translationAnimation and combine the two into a set, I find the below easier):

```
transTo.setRepeatCount(1);
transTo.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

3rdly and maybe you already know, but this is a view animation, so the button is just going to visually change where it is drawn, not where it can be clicked. If that is fine for your purposes then go ahead with the view animation. To move the clickable area I recommend a property animation. I wrote a blog about them here [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/2d-animation-for-android-series-comparing-and-contrasting-different-ways-of-doing-the-same) and also about view animation [HERE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/2d-animation-for-android-series-comparing-and-contrasting-different-ways-of-doing-the-same-part-II)